# Why while loop is filling only the first condition?

Tags: c

while loop give result back when one of the condition succeed , i need both of them, any help

```
#include <stdio.h>

int   yRechner()
{  
   
    int x = 2;
    int y =0;
    int i =0;
    char answer[2];

    while (i < 1 && y <= x)
    {
        printf("is the wall here pleas answer yes(Y/y) or No(N/n) \n");

        scanf("%s", &answer);

        if (answer[0] == 'N' || answer[0] == 'n')
        {
            printf("one step \n");
            y++;
        }
        else if (answer[0] == 'Y' || answer[0] == 'y')
        {
            if (i < 1 && y > x)
            {
                i++;
                printf("rotate \n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("am not seeing the wall please say no. \n");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("wrong answer \n");
        }
    }

    return y;
}

int main()
{

    int y = yRechner();
    printf("y = %d\n", y);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through this code, step by step, in a debugger?

Comment: i  am new with c  i don't know how to use debugging

Comment: Good time now to learn to use a debugger. It only takes a few minutes to get started and will save you hours of pain now and forever more.

Comment: You have while ( y <= x ) but/than you check if ( y > x ). Is it true ?

Comment: @Gromph i don't believe it is a problem

Comment: Then you need to take another look. @Gromph is right. It will not be possible to enter that case.

Comment: it doesn't matter , whatever you did, the case will finish as soon as one of the condition have been done

Answer (score 0):

It isn't apparent whether these conditions, `i < 1` and `y <= x`, are negated or not. In general, if you want to loop while not both of the conditions are true, `!(c1 && c2)`, you can use [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to simplify `!c1 || !c2`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a Solution , thx for your hints

```
#include <stdio.h>

int   yRechner()
{  
   
int x = 2;
int y =0;
int i =0;
char answer[2];

while (i < 1 )
{
    printf("is the wall here please answer yes(Y/y) or No(N/n) \n");

    scanf("%s", &answer);

    if (answer[0] == 'N' || answer[0] == 'n')
    {
        printf("one step \n");
        y++;
    }
    else if (answer[0] == 'Y' || answer[0] == 'y')
    {
        if (i < 1 && y > x )
        {
            i++;
            printf("rotate \n");
            continue;
        }
        else if (i < 1 && y < x)
        {
            printf("am not seeing the wall please say no. \n");
            continue;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("wrong answer \n");
    }
}

return y;
}

int main()
{
int y = yRechner();
printf("y = %d\n", y);

return 0;
}
```